# Determining the UI thread in another process

Tags: c#, user-interface

Is it possible in C# to determine which thread in another application that was opened by my process is the UI thread?

Comment: How did you open the other application?  Also: why?

Comment: I opened it with "Process.Start". Why? I need to check if the process is stuck (i.e. Not processing the messages in its message queue). I tried the "IsResponding" property of the process, but it's always "true".

Comment: is the other app under your source control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@HansPassant has already [answered it on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/42de8f6a-61f4-495e-a69d-bd018e07c6f7):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
public static ProcessThread GetUIThread(Process proc) {
  if (proc.MainWindowHandle == null) return null;
  int id = GetWindowThreadProcessId(proc.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
  foreach (ProcessThread pt in proc.Threads)
    if (pt.Id == id) return pt;
  return null;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr procid);
```